# Best practice for not delivering certain mails in development

Tags: ruby-on-rails

We have a center/course platform. Every time a new student is interested in a course we send an email to de center to notify them about it.

However, we don't want this to happen in development, as centers would receive 'false' notifications.

Firs thing comes to my mind is introducing `unless Rails.env == 'production'` wherever we don't want to send an email. But it feels a little bit weird.

What would it be the best solution/pattern to accomplish this?

Note that we don't want to stop sending mails to everyone, but just some of them.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: why don't you use https://github.com/ryanb/letter_opener for development environment?

Answer (score 0):

In your config/environments/development.rb (and test.rb) you can do:

```
Rails.application.configure do
  #.......other config here
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :test
end
```

This does not send the email, but you can see it in the log file/terminal output

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for is this:

Add this to your `config/environments/development.rb`

```
config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = false
```

or

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :test
```

to log the deliveries

(If you're using ActionMailer)